# Reducing the size of frozen model converting into tfjs model

Tags: tensorflow.js, tensorflowjs-converter

I have a frozen model of 96mb and using "quantization 1" I have reduced it to 24MB.

Is there a way to reduce this size further, I want my size to be in between 10-12MB (Preferably 10MB)

Thanks

Comment: What about 8-bit quantization?

Comment: If you mean converting from Float32 to Uint8 then yeah this I have done using this quantization 1 flag.

Comment: not much you can do (and probably already have serious clipping - i've rarely seen models that maintain precision when quantized to uint8) other than retrain model with lower resolution - that reduces the weights sizes.

other than that, if you're really familiar with this models architecture, perhaps you can prune some layers from a model prior to freezing it - again with idea to remove some weights.

Comment: Yeah, @VladimirMandic thought so. also, I came across this "https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.02531.pdf" paper for reducing model size.